# What is a Standalone host?

Tags: platform, blade

I am fairly new to how Software platforms can be setup architecturally.

I was told that there is a platform at our company that is a Standalone host as it is built on Blades.

So my question is what is a Standalone host and how is it different to one that is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this question is a bit context dependent.

Generally speaking, in the Internet world, a standalone host is a system residing on its own server, as opposed to a shared host, where multiple websites or similar are located on a single machine.   Another alternative to a standalone host would be a Virtual Host, where a single system is carved up into multiple systems.

Blades are machines which have pretty-much all their own infrastructure, except for a shared chassis, for greater density, thus each blade is its own machine.   The word "Standalone Host" does not really fit if you have multiple blades all serving a purpose.    If, however, you are using just 1 machine and there are a number of similar machines for others, each on its own blade (all in the same chassis for example), then yes, you would be a standalone host.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to explain it is *independant of others*.

If all the software from the host can be put on another machine in a different location, and if doing so breaks none of the services it provides or uses, then it would be a stand alone host.

A host that is not stand alone may rely on elements in the LAN for user authentication, storage, boot image and so on.